# Is it possible to configure WSS 2.0 in a way to access the wss 2.0 via the internet?

Tags: sharepoint, windows-sbs-2003, wss

I'm trying to configure an old Windows Share Point Server 2.0 so that it will be reachable via internet or a least by a url other than http://companyweb/. Is this possible?

It is running on Windows Small Business Server 2003

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly are you seeing problems? Have you created an appropriate DNS entry and set up alternate access mappings (or created a site with the desired URL via stsadm) in the Sharepoint configuration?

In the meantime you could read up [this blog article](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/mglaser/archive/2007/01/31/hosting-sharepoint-on-a-fully-qualified-domain-name-fqdn.aspx) for some examples for WSS 2.0 as well as 3.0.

Also, consider upgrading to a newer version (WSS' current name is "Sharepoint Foundation 2010", but it will only run on 64-bit Windows Server 2008 platforms, so you will have to go with WSS 3.0) - WSS 2.0 is ancient.

Comment: I did not created an dns entry, this would be the next step if now how can configure the sharepoint virutal server that it will also to an url inside of my iis standard root some like: http://server-ip/sharepoint. I also thout about to create a new site but then i have still the same problem, this side listens again to http://newsite/ and not to http://server-ip/sharepoint.
An upgrade is no solution for the moment, because we need the solution for this server version.

Comment: I believe WSS does extend the default virtual server upon installation. After that, it's just a matter of configuring the virtual paths as [described in the docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287929(v=office.12).aspx). Note that when you are going to use "Scalable Hosting Mode" (aka host-based site collections), you will no longer be able to configure path-based site collections - the sharepoint services will take over the entire site in this case. I believe this might be what SBS has done by creating the `companyweb` virtual server and the accompanying site.